# Get a git diff from changes from multiple separate specific commits?

Tags: git

A git log (in reverse chronological order) shows:

commit eeee 
commit dddd 
commit cccc 
commit bbbb 
commit aaaa

I want to generate a patch file from commits bbbb, dddd, and eeee.

I could make one for bbbb by `git diff aaaa bbbb` and I could make one for dddd and eeee by `git diff cccc` or `git diff cccc eeee`.

How can I make one patch file that contains the changes from those three commits but not commit cccc?

Thanks!

Comment: checkout a branch on bbbb and cherry pick dddd eeee into the branch then you can create patch from last three commits? you can probably do it with rebasing as well

Comment: @LukeHutton Thanks! That would work, though would be nice if there were a way to do it without creating new branches.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to create a patch file:

```
for hash in bbbb dddd eeee; do git diff $hash^..$hash; done > patchfile
```

Then apply it using:

```
patch -p1 < patchfile
```

Answer (score 1):

`$git log` Copy sha id of 2-3 different commits and then run git diff command with those sha-ids.

```
$git diff (sha-id one) (sha-id two)  -- path/to/file
```